# SAS : Eliminate duplicates if a condition is satisfied

Tags: duplicates, sas

I want to eliminate duplicates from a database, based on an identifier, an order and a condition.

More precisely, I have data with several observations. I have sometimes a condition that makes me want to keep that observation anyway (let fix it *condition=1*), but then also keep the observation with the same identifier even if this condition does not hold (*condition=0*).

But if I have for one identifier several observations where *condition=0* then I want to elminate duplicates, with criterion being having the greatest *order*.

Without the condition I can do that

```
proc sort data=have;
    by identifier descending order;
run;

proc sort nudopkey data=have;
    by identifier;
run;
```

But how to incorporate my condition in this ?

**Edit 1 : add a database example :**

```
data Test; 
   input identifier $ order condition; 
   datalines;
1023 1 0
1023 2 0
1064 2 0
1064 1 0
1098 1 0
1098 1 1
;
```

Then I want to keep

- 1023 2 0
- 1064 2 0
- 1098 1 0
- 1098 1 1

**Edit 2 : tried to precise my conditions**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to eliminate duplicates only when the condition for all records for an identifier is set to 0.  In that case you want to keep the record with the maximum order and eliminate all other records with the same identifier.

```
Proc sql; 
         create  table   want    as 
         select  * 
         from    test 
         group   by      identifier 
         having  max (condition) ne      0 
         or      order           eq      max (order) 
         ; 
Quit;
```

This will keep all rows for an Identifier where the maximum condition = 1, 
or in the case of those where maximum condition = 0, select the row with the maximum order.

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thx a lot ! Precisely I wanted to eliminate duplicates as long as condition=0, whether there is an observation with condition=1 or not. But it can easily be obtained from your example by changing the having condition in having condition ne 0.

Comment: In fact I have another question : the different conditions you put in the having option are read and executed in order ? If I have two order variables for instance, but want to check one first, which is more valid

Comment: Order is irrelevant.  If either condition is satisfied then the record is written to output table. Both conditions are independent.

Comment: You could reverse the order of the conditions but it would not have any effect on the resulting output table.

Comment: To answer your second question - You should be able to impose some order of processing conditions against various columns by embedding case statement(s) in your Having clause.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this depends on how you define 'condition'.  Is your condition easily verifiable on every record for that identifier?  Then you can do something like this.

1. Evaluate the condition.
2. For records where it is true (you want to remove the duplicate), set flag=0.  For records where it is not true, increment the condition flag by one.

If the condition is true for all records in that ID, all will have the same value (flag=0) and nodupkey on `by identifier flag;` will remove extras.  If the condition is false for all records, those will not be removed. If it's true for some and false for some, and you want to remove only some of the records with that identifier (only the duplicates where it is true), then you have to make sure that either it's sorted to have all of the condition=true records at top, or have a separate flag counter that determines what value the flag will be (since it sometimes will go to 0 in the middle, so `0 0 0 1 2 3 0 4 5 6` is what you want, not `0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2` ).

Perhaps easier to see is to do it within a datastep.  After sorting `by identifier descending order`:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by identifier descending order;
  if (condition=true) and not (first.identifier) then delete;
run;
```

This will, again, work if either condition=true is always at the top, or if it's always consistent within one ID group.  If it's inconsistent and mixed, then you need to keep track of whether you've kept one where it was true (assuming you want to), or it might delete all records where it is true; use a separate variable to keep track of how many you've kept.  `first.identifier` will be 1/TRUE for the first record for that identifier only, not taking into account the condition.  You could also create the flag, then sort `by identifier flag descending order;` and guarantee the condition=true are at the top (either by making flag=0 for true, or sorting by `descending flag`.)

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise. As I understant your answer, the problem with my database is that the condition is not true for all the records in that ID. It just indicates to me that I have to keep one more observation.